# Python array access notation

Tags: python

I have a very quick question about the notation on accessing an array in python.

Is this line:

```
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict) + look_back, :] = trainPredict
```

I've seen arrays are being accessed like this `x[a:b]` but never like this `x[a:b,:]`

Can someone explain me with detail what this line of code is doing? What does it mean to put colon before the closing bracket? What about the comma?

Comment: That is a NumPy slice. It is actually `m[a:b, :]`. Note the comma. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use x[a:b], it means that you are taking the elements from position "a" (x[a]) to position "b" (x[b]) of a one dimensional array.
For the second case x[a:b,:], it is a two dimensional "a" to position "b" of the first dimension of the array, and all the elements of the second dimension of the array, in other words, from  x[a][first element] to x[b][last element].

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Expanding on that notation then is it possible to add as many comas as dimensions my array has?